# C++ variables declaration within enum declaration

Tags: c++, variables, types, enums, declaration

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum Week_Day {SAT, SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI} wd1 = FRI;

Week_Day wd2 = SAT;

int main()
{
    cout << "\n " << wd1;
    cout << "\n " << wd2;

    cout << "\n\n\n";
}
```

I searched for the difference(s) between the ways `wd1` and `wd2` were declared, but it seemed to me that it was just a matter of convenience.

Is it true, or I missed something?

Update1:

OK, both `wd1` and `wd2` are now global variables.

Are there any other differences?

Comment: well, the diffrence is that `wd1` is a global variable, while `wd2` is not...

Comment: Read up on [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) and [storage classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep at the first one it define the enum and immediately used it to declare the wd1
and second one is another declaration without the need to redefine again.
no difference same code two different places.
another difference would be because of position in code they defined , the first  one is global but the second one is local.
Global means the variable can be used everywhere in your code and everybody  know it. but local variables only have life-cycle inside a block

```
{
SomeClass someVar;// defined here

...

// die here, the destructor will be called automatically by the runtime here
}
```

Suggest to read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)

Comment: Getting closer, but to be a useful answer you'll need to expand on what it means to be local and global.